# Can I write single byte to a file without temporary variable?

Tags: c++, ofstream, ppm

I have a simple debug function that writes bytes to a file that will be displayed as image. It follows `ppm` format.

Originally, I used this:

```
static void SaveDebugImage(const std::string& filePath, const unsigned char* psdata, const int resolution)
{
  // Debug: print stored data in file
  std::ofstream file;
  file.open(filePath, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
  if (!file.is_open())
  {
    // Throws error and crashes the program on purpose
    RError("[ImageDebug::SaveDebugImage] Cannot write to %s", filePath.c_str());
  }

  file << "P6"
    << "\n"
    << resolution << "\n"
    << resolution << "\n"
    << "255"
    << "\n";

  const char zero = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < resolution * resolution; ++i)
  {

    file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(pxdata), sizeof(*pxdata));
    ++pxdata;
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(pxdata), sizeof(*pxdata));
    ++pxdata;
    file.write(&zero, sizeof(zero));
    ++pxdata;
  }
  file.flush();
  file.close();
}
```

You can see it skips last byte of color, that's because the data are not strictly RGB image, but rather a meta information format. R, G and B channels mean something else than color. You can also observe the need for `const char zero = 0` that I have to use to write zeros.

I now have a function on hand that really provides the surface color, it may look like this:

```
OurLibrary::Color getRealColor(byte r, byte g, byte b);
```

Now assuming this fictional `Color` class has a `unsigned char getR() const` method, how can I write the result to file without temporary variable. Now I have to do this:

```
OurLibrary::Color pixelColor(getRealColor( ... ));
const unsigned char colorR = pixelColor.getR();
file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&colorR), sizeof(colorR));
```

I would prefer:

```
file.write(pixelColor.getR());
```

Is there any such method? I couldn't find it in docs.

Comment: FYI I think the call to `.flush` before `.close` is superfluous?

Comment: does `getR` return by reference or value?  If it returns by reference just use it directly.

Comment: @NathanOliver Updated question, it returns a value.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Won't that add a string representation? I am writing in binary format - 1 byte per color.

Comment: Easiest option is to just change `getR` to return by reference.  Then you can use `file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&pixelColor.getR()), sizeof(pixelColor.getR()));`

Comment: Can you add a method to `OurLibrary::Color` to write or serialize to a file?

Comment: _"Is there any such method? I couldn't find it in docs."_ Really? It's right there, immediately above `write`, which you're already using, alongside a clear description of exactly what you want to do ("insert a character").

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Anyone can miss something obvious. I wouldn't waste time writing a long question if I had found the part of docs you're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream), [`put`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/put) "inserts a character".

So, simply:

```
file.put(pixelColor.getR());
```

<sub>*(You **may** need to cast to `char` to avoid some narrowing-conversion warnings; not sure.)*</sub>

---

Also, that `flush()` is completely pointless. C++ streams flush on close.